# Specifying MSK credentials in an AWS CDK stack

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-msk

I have code that seems to "almost" deploy. It will fail with the following error:

```
10:55:25 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping | QFDSKafkaEventSour...iltynotifyEFE73996
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: The secret provided in 'sourceAccessConfigurations' is not associated with cluster some-valid-an. Please provide a secret associated with the cluster. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: some-uuid )" (RequestToken: some-uuid, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

I've cobbled together the cdk stack from multiple tutorials, trying to learn CDK. I've gotten it to the point that I can deploy a lambda, specify one (or more) layers for the lambda, and even specify any of several different sources for triggers. But our production Kafka requires credentials... and I can't figure out for the life of me how to supply those so that this will deploy correctly.

Obviously, those credentials shouldn't be included in the git repo of my codebase. I assume I will have to set up a Secrets Manager secret with part or all of the values. We're using scram-sha-512, and it includes a user/pass pair. The 'secret_name' value to Secret() is probably the name/path of the Secrets Manager secret. I have no idea what the second, unnamed param is for, and I'm having trouble figuring that out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Stack code follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_lambda as lambda_,
    App, Duration, Stack
)
from aws_cdk.aws_lambda_event_sources import ManagedKafkaEventSource
from aws_cdk.aws_secretsmanager import Secret

class ExternalRestEndpoint(Stack):

    def __init__(self, app: App, id: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(app, id)

        secret = Secret(self, "Secret", secret_name="integrations/msk/creds")

        msk_arn = "some valid and confirmed arn"

        # Lambda layer.
        lambdaLayer = lambda_.LayerVersion(self, 'lambda-layer',
            code = lambda_.AssetCode('utils/lambda-deployment-packages/lambda-layer.zip'),
            compatible_runtimes = [lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7],
        )  

        # Source for the lambda.
        with open("src/path/to/sourcefile.py", encoding="utf8") as fp:
            mysource_code = fp.read()

        # Config for it.
        lambdaFn = lambda_.Function(
            self, "QFDS",
            code=lambda_.InlineCode(mysource_code),
            handler="lambda_handler",
            timeout=Duration.seconds(300),
            runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
            layers=[lambdaLayer],
        )

        # Set up the event (managed Kafka). 
        lambdaFn.add_event_source(ManagedKafkaEventSource(
            cluster_arn=prototype_mks,
            topic="foreign.endpoint.availabilty.notify", 
            secret=secret,
            batch_size=100,                # default
            starting_position=lambda_.StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into a code sample, I understand that you are working with Amazon MSK as an event source, and not just self-managed (cross-account) Kafka.

> I assume I will have to set up a Secrets Manager secret with part or all of the values

You don't need to setup credentials. If you use [MSK with SALS_SCRAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-password.html), you [already have credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/1.0/apireference/operations.html), which must be `associated` with MSK cluster.

As you can see from the doc, you secret name should start with `AmazonMSK_`, for example `AmazonMSK_LambdaSecret`.

So, in the code above, you will need to fix this line:

```py
secret = Secret(self, "Secret", secret_name="AmazonMSK_LambdaSecret")
```

I assume you already aware of the [CDK python doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_event_sources/README.html#kafka), but will just add here for reference.

Comment: I am aware of the document, thank you. I don't understand what the "secret" line does... is it telling CDK to have the lambda read from a configured secret, or is it creating a new secret in Secrets Manager? Is this something else entirely? Someone else set up MSK, and the doc seems to indicate that he would have had to have already created that secret, so I guess I'm just reading from it with this? Forgive me if all this sounds dumb, I'm more of the sort of guy who writes the lambda code, but if I wait for dev ops to build this out, it'll take too long.

Comment: @JohnO, you are right, I missed where the focus of your question was. The line above will indeed create new secret, which is not what you would need. In python CDK, in order to use **existing** secret you would need to know secret's ARN and use [fromSecretAttributes()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/get_secrets_manager_value.html).

Comment: Thanks so much. That's the call I need, I just have four secets to check through all named "AmazonMSK_something".

Comment: I've got from_secret_attributes running correctly but it complains that my role can't access it. I think this means I have to do iam.Role.from_role_arn(), and that succeeds for a role that has permission, but then it doesn't use this role for the secretsmanager. Instead it goes back to using whatever default role (auto-generated, I think?).

Comment: IIRC, the role, which is used to deploy the stack, needs to have permissions to list/describe a secret by that ARN you use in stack. When your lambda runs, the role assigned to lambda execution will need an access to describe and to get secret's value.